# Chisquare Test Prob

Tags: python, dataframe, statistics, missing-data, chi-squared

I wish you good work. can you answer my question. Thank you
Does the chi-square p value between two categorical variables show the correlation of categorical variables? When we compare the p values, can we say that the small p value is highly correlated?

I compared the chi-square test results for categorical features. I thought of filling the column by taking the one with the strong correlation[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjJ3p.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the chi-square p-value between two categorical variables does not show the correlation between them. A small p-value indicates a significant association, but it does not indicate the strength or direction of that association. Correlation measures like Cramer's V or phi coefficient are used to assess the strength of association between categorical variables.